# how to make multiple REST calls to same method

Tags: java, spring-rest

I have a requirement, where I need to return list of objects from Spring REST method.
But, I need to split those objects by 100.. Let's say if the response objects are more than 400, the method should be called 5 times and every time I need to send 100 objects.

How to implement this scenario? How can I explicitly make multiple calls to the same method? Is it possible?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How would you know in advance that your rest method will return more than 400 objects?

Comment: Could you share what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

The term you are looking for is pagination. One of the example ([source and more details](https://ankushs92.github.io/tutorial/2016/05/03/pagination-with-spring-boot.html)):

```
@RestController
class PersonController {
    
    final PersonService personService
    
    @Autowired
    PersonController( PersonService personService ){
        this.personService = personService
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/persons",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    Page<Person> list( Pageable pageable){
        Page<Person> persons = personService.listAllByPage(pageable)
        persons
    } 
}
```

`/persons?page=0&size=3` would return a batch of the first 3 persons from the database. `/persons?page=1&size=3` would return the next batch.

Notice that we haven’t passed `RequestParams` to our handler method . When the endpoint `/persons?page=0&size=3` is hit, Spring would automatically resolve the **page** and **size** parameters and create a **Pageable** instance . We would then pass this **Pageable** instance to the Service layer ,which would pass it to our Repository layer .